# Spring boot with hibernate persisting table data in db

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I create one embeddable class that holds the composite key

```
@Embeddable
public class TaskCategoryPK  implements Serializable{

@Column(name = "Task_taskId")
private Long taskid;
@Column(name = "Category_categoryId")
private Long categoryid;

public TaskCategoryPK() {}

public TaskCategoryPK(Long taskid,Long categoryid) {
    this.taskid = taskid;
    this.categoryid = categoryid;
}

public void setTaskid(Long taskid) {
    this.taskid = taskid;
}

public void setCategoryid(Long categoryid) {
    this.categoryid = categoryid;
}

public Long getTaskid() {
    return taskid;
}

public Long getCategoryid() {
    return categoryid;
}


}
```

I created the entity class that maps to this composite key class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TaskCategoryMapping")
public class TaskCategoryMapping {

@EmbeddedId
private TaskCategoryPK taskcategorypk;

public TaskCategoryPK getTaskCategoryPK() {
    return taskcategorypk;
}

public void setTaskCategoryPK(TaskCategoryPK taskCategoryPK) {
    this.taskcategorypk = taskCategoryPK;
}
}
```

In controller i was trying to persist data in db through the resource but it's throwing null pointer exception. Controller handling

```
TaskCategoryPK taskCategoryPK = new TaskCategoryPK(1L,2L);
        TaskCategoryMapping taskCategoryMapping = new TaskCategoryMapping();
        taskCategoryMapping.setTaskCategoryPK(taskCategoryPK);
        taskCategoryResource.save(taskCategoryMapping);
```

But i get the below exception

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the BootController code?

Comment: Hi @rick i didn't add autowired to that repository, that was causing the problem. Thnx.